# Given $ax^2+by^2+cxy > 0$, what can I deduce about $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that for any nonzero $x,y\in\mathbf{R}$,

$$ax^2+by^2+cxy > 0,$$

where $a,b,c\in\mathbf{R}$. What can I deduce about $a$, $b$, and $c$?

---

For example, letting $x=1$ and $y=0$, I know that $\boxed{a>0}$. Letting $x=0$ and $y=1$, I know that $\boxed{b>0}$. Letting $x=y=1$, I know that $\boxed{c>-(a+b)}$.

What else can I deduce about $a$, $b$, and $c$? How will I know when it's time to stop looking? (Is that last question even answerable?)

Comment: You can "complete the square" as you would for solving a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write
$$ax^2+by^2+cxy=a\left(x+\frac{c}{2a}\,y\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{c^2}{4a}\right)y^2$$
by completing the square. This is a sum of two squares. In order to ensure that it's always positive, the coefficients both have to be positive, so
$$a>0$$
and
$$c^2<4ab.$$

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the whole thing by $y^2$ , we get $a(x/y)^2+c(x/y)+b>0$ (Note: we can divide by $y^2$ since it is non zero)
Since it is positive for all values of $(x/y)$, the discriminant must be negative (since $a$ is given to be positive)
Therefore, $c^2 - 4 ab < 0$

Comment: Jonathan's method is more explanatory.

Comment: Do you mean the discriminant?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out :)