# Inequality of real numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x,y,a,b~\text{and}~ c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a,b>0$. Then show that $ax^2+by^2+2cxy \geq 0$ and $(ab-c^2)>0$. Please help to prove this. I tried AM GM inequality but did not  succeeded.

Comment: You can always choose $c \in \Bbb R$ such that the expression becomes negative (unless $x=y=0$). Did you forget some condition on $a,b,c$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193561/42969 for a correct version.

Comment: Yes, I forgot but now I have mentioned that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given $ax^2+by^2+cxy > 0$, what can I deduce about $a$, $b$, and $c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219847/given-ax2by2cxy-0-what-can-i-deduce-about-a-b-and-c)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193561/42969

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to find out this question on this site thats why I posted it here.

Comment: Should I delete this question? Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False. Take $a=b=x=y=1$ and $c =-2$.

Answer for the modified question: $ax^{2}+by^{2}+2cxy \geq ax^{2}+by^{2}-2|c||x||y|=(\sqrt{a}|x|-\sqrt {b}|y|)^{2} +2\sqrt {|a||b|} |x||y| -2c |x||y| \geq 0$.

Comment: Please sir see the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks sir for your awesome reply

Comment: Please guide me what should I do to? It is mentioned above that this is a duplicate question. Will this harm to my reputation on this site?